# Can't connect to Azure from OPC UA client

Tags: java, azure, opc

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm trying to create an OPC UA client that can send information to an Azure IoT Hub.

Everytime the OPC UA client reads a value from the OPC UA server, that value and the name of the node must be sent to Azure IoT Hub.

I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted#comments-container and I successfully created a simulated device that is able to connect to the Hub and send messages to it.

On the other hand, I have working OPC UA client that can connect with the OPC UA server and read values from it.

I used the code in the example I linked above to modify my OPC UA client to send messages to the Hub in the read operation. I'm using the same connection string and device Id that I used in the tutorial.

I'm able to build and run the modified OPC UA client, but the messages does not arrive to the Hub whatsoever.

I noticed that the execution gets stuck in the statement "client_azure.open()" for about 10 minutes, then it continues the execution, so I believe that it is not able to open the connection to the Hub, but I don't know why.

My code would be like this:

```
public class OPCUAclient {  //main class of the OPC UA client

    private static String connString = "HostName=XXXXX;DeviceId=YYYYYY;SharedAccessKey=ZZZZZZZ";
    private static IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS;
    private static String deviceId = "YYYYYYY";
    private static DeviceClient client_azure;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        client_azure = new DeviceClient(connString, protocol);
        client_azure.open();        //Here is where the application takes like 10 minutes  to react
           .
           .
           .
           azure_client.close()
     }

    //OPC UA code
   .
   .
   .        
   //inside a method of the OPC UA code, I execute the following

   MessageSender sender = new MessageSender();
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
     executor.execute(sender);
     //System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit.");
   //System.in.read();
   executor.shutdownNow();

   .
   .
   .

   //At the end of the OPCUAclient class, the following methods are defined

    private static class TelemetryDataPoint {
           public String deviceId;
           public String node; 
           public int value;
           TelemetryDataPoint(int value_t, String node_t){
                 value = value_t;
                 node=node_t;
            }
            public String serialize() {
                  Gson gson = new Gson();
                  return gson.toJson(this);
             }
      }
      private static class EventCallback implements IotHubEventCallback
      {
            public void execute(IotHubStatusCode status, Object context) {
                  System.out.println("IoT Hub responded to message with status: " + status.name());

                  if (context != null) {
                        synchronized (context) {
                              context.notify();
                        }
                  }
             }
      }


      private static class MessageSender implements Runnable {
            public int value; 
            public String node;  //NodeId
            MessageSender(){  
                 value = 1; //value_azure;
                 node = "Blue"; //node_azure;
            }
           public void run()  {
                  try{
                         TelemetryDataPoint telemetryDataPoint = new TelemetryDataPoint(value, node);
                         telemetryDataPoint.deviceId = deviceId;
                         String msgStr = telemetryDataPoint.serialize();
                         Message msg = new Message(msgStr);
                         System.out.println("Sending: " + msgStr);
                         Object lockobj = new Object();
                         EventCallback callback = new EventCallback();

                         client_azure.sendEventAsync(msg, callback, lockobj);
                         synchronized (lockobj) {
                               lockobj.wait();
                }
               Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          System.out.println("Finished.");
                }
         }
     }
}
```

Any idea on what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any exception on running the code `OPCUAclient`? Is the code `OPCUAclient` running on the same environment with the offical sample code? Per my experience, I think you need to check the network for `OPCUAclient` that whether connect IoTHub via some proxy servers or the network not support AMQP. Any update or concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Check the Azure example included with the OPC Foundation Java Stack: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java/tree/master/examples/publisher

Comment: Hi Jouni Aro, I'm experiencing some trouble with the example. 

I downloaded and installed OPC Foundation Java Stack using Maven, then I go to Publisher folder where the POM file is located and compile the example by "mvn clean compile" and it says "BUILD SUCCESS".

But when I try to run it with 'mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.microsoft.azure.iothub.ClientPublisher" ' an error prompts. It says:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project opc-ua-stack: 

Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: By the way, I'm still investigating where the error might come from, when I have more clues I will give you feedback.